# Automatic Serial Number in table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the code below to do an automatic serial number, but the thing that I want to  do is:

I've created two tables in `Sheet1 ("Table1")& ("Table2")` and I want to apply this code to them individually.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myrange = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lrow, 2))
    For Each cell In myrange
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = i + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use formula instead of VBA for getting the Sl.# for your table.

Table has a special functionality that if a cell is filled with a formula then it will automatically fill rest of the cells of that column with the initial formula.

So in the second line of your table Sl.# Column (1st line meant for Table Column Headers) just copy paste the below formula.

**=ROWS($1:1)**

Comment: thanks my friend but I like to use it as VBA help you better here as no number will appear unless there is word/s in cell B, also if i want to use a formula I can use the following : =if(B2<>,"",1,"") and in the second row =if(B3<>"", 1+B2,""). this can serve my request better. anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: But the formula you stated will throw errors when any of the row is getting deleted.  But in my suggested formula you won't face the #REF error since it will get auto adjusted.

Comment: you are right, but yours also needs to put it in If-Condition to do the same function like this =IF(E10<>"",ROWS($1:1),""). this is a good to be used but I really want to know who can this apply in VBA in one sheet in two table. as I do not want anyone to clear the formula in the table as it is used by different users. this is the issue.